# keyError when using word_tokenize in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to run a sentiment analysis problem with keras and the IMDB datset, but when I try to tokenize the text, I get a key error

```
import numpy as np
from keras.datasets import imdb
import json
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=5000)
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
X_train = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen = 500)
X_test = sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen = 500)

from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding, LSTM, Dense, Dropout

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(5000, 32, input_length = 500))
model.add(LSTM(units = 100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
print(model.summary())
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 64, epochs = 6)

good = "A great movie"
bad = "This was not a great movie"

from nltk import word_tokenize
from keras.preprocessing import sequence

word2index = imdb.get_word_index()
X=[]
for word in word_tokenize(good):
     X.append(word2index[word])
X=sequence.pad_sequences([X],maxlen=500)

loaded_model.predict(X)
```

It didn't get to the prediction part, as I got an error

```
 File "<ipython-input-51-9268dcdfa83f>", line 9, in <module>
    test.append(word2index[word])

KeyError: 'A'
```

What do I do to solve this issue?

Comment: What is `good`? Please post a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post the whole error message, with full traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its good practice to avoid upper case words and use `.lower()` on strings.

Your character `A` doesn't exist in `word2index` dict but `a` does. You'll notice that every element in `word2index`is lowercase.

So if you do `X.append(word2index[word.lower()])` you should get the the appropriate results.

Answer (score 0):

First of, the error is reproducible with just this code:

```py
from keras.datasets import imdb
from nltk import word_tokenize

good = "A great movie"

word2index = imdb.get_word_index()
X=[]
for word in word_tokenize(good):
     X.append(word2index[word])

print(X)
```

The problem is that `word`=`A` is not in the `word2index` dictionary. As described in the [Tensorflow/Keras documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/imdb/get_word_index), the method `get_word_index()` [returns a dictionary](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/imdb/get_word_index) converted from *imdb_word_index.json*.

You can check the contents of that dictionary. As noted in the API doc, the `imdb` dataset is downloaded locally to *~/.keras/datasets/imdb_word_index.json*. It is downloaded automatically the first time you access it or you can also download it manually from https://s3.amazonaws.com/text-datasets/imdb_word_index.json.

You'll see that *imdb_word_index.json* are all in lowercase characters. So the resulting `word2index` dictionary will also have keys that are all in lowercase.

The solution is to also use lowercase when checking against that dataset.

```py
for word in word_tokenize(good.lower()):
     X.append(word2index[word])

print(X)  # [3, 84, 17]
```